# how do i specify psedo class attributes inline?

Tags: html, css, google-sites, inline-styles

This wiki I'm using (Google Sites) does not support linking of style sheets or even  tags in its HTML mode (It sucks, I know). The only way to specify styles is to define them inline.

I need to put a menu bar now. I've figured out a pure css menubar, but I'm having trouble defining the hover class inline. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using Google sites? If you're savvy enough to be writing HTML/CSS but too cheap to pay for hosting... there are still plenty of better free alternatives, no?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-class attributes are not well supported for inline styles, but you can use Javascript, such as

```
<a href="page.html" style="color: red;" onmouseover="this.style.color = 'blue'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'red'">Link</a>
```

Comment: No, Google Sites does not support this either.

Comment: It doesn't support JavaScript? The only way it can *not* support it is if it goes out of its way to *strip it out*. Its your browser that needs to parse this, not Google Sites.